# How to slide entire webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-animate, effects

For example - http://www.tumblr.com

Log out and try to click buttons "Log In", "Sign up", "30 reasons why you'll love Tumblr" (especially interesting).

How to create this slide effect?

P.S: i'm not asking for provide me working code, just guidelines and advices.

**UP:** seems like i found the possible solution. Code from tumblr js files.

```
return new Effect.Move(element, {
x: initialMoveX,
y: initialMoveY,
duration: 0.01,
beforeSetup: function(effect) {
  effect.element.hide().makeClipping().makePositioned();
},
afterFinishInternal: function(effect) {
  new Effect.Parallel(
    [ new Effect.Opacity(effect.element, { sync: true, to: 1.0, from: 0.0, transition: options.opacityTransition }),
      new Effect.Move(effect.element, { x: moveX, y: moveY, sync: true, transition: options.moveTransition }),
      new Effect.Scale(effect.element, 100, {
        scaleMode: { originalHeight: dims.height, originalWidth: dims.width },
        sync: true, scaleFrom: window.opera ? 1 : 0, transition: options.scaleTransition, restoreAfterFinish: true})
    ], Object.extend({
         beforeSetup: function(effect) {
           effect.effects[0].element.setStyle({height: '0px'}).show();
         },
         afterFinishInternal: function(effect) {
           effect.effects[0].element.undoClipping().undoPositioned().setStyle(oldStyle);
         }
       }, options)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll find a working demo of a full-page slide here: http://acarna.com/full-page-slide.php

View the source and the CSS as both are requird for this to work. The main keys to note are...

- You need a container in which 2 (or more) screen-sized pages are held (#wrapper in my demo)
- This container needs to have its overflow property set to hidden
- You must detect the screen height each time you run the animation (in case the window size has changed)

Comment: This version is much easier, it isn't like tumblr's, because this slide is performed within a page without url changing. You could see tumblr's url changing from /login to /register when sliding performs, that's the point.

Comment: @LotusH I see what you mean - on clicking the 'log in' link (for example), the page doesn't load the way an HTML page normally loads. But neither is the content being pulled in by Ajax. Have you examined Tumbler's source as suggested above? You'll find they're using Prototype, have a very interesting set of body tag parameters, and a suspicious looking log-in link. The parameters in the body tag and log-in link remind me of the way pages are handled by jQuery Mobile, and I suspect are the key to the effect you're after.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try both of suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you check out the scripts and css they have used in their pages?
just check it out you will get the clue how to do it.

Comment: You can use firebug addon in firefox to view all scripts and code.

Answer (score 2):

I made this effect on my own site too. I don't know how tumblr did that, but I have figured out my own way to do this(for tumblr's effect as an example):

step 1. before redirect to a new url, slide the bottom section up of current page
step 2. slide down the top section when the new url document.ready

---

Update years later:

Since I just got a new vote-up, I discovered this old answer which is now a little bit outdated.

With modern javascript, you just need to use `history.pushstate`, all effects are performed in one page. After changing the page content with js, you can use pushstate to change the url, which makes it like navigating with effects.

To read more about pushstate, please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for advice.